# Ad-hoc capability SQL SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, adhoc, adhoc-queries

We are in the process of doing techincal design. We would like to know what is the Ad-hoc Capability part of SSRS. We have done some POC with Report Model and building reports with Report builder.

Options 2 : Build Analysis Services Universe and expose that through the Report builder.

I would like to know from the group each approach what are the benifts and disadvantages. I am also looking if you have any suggestion on the Report Builder books or resource which i can refer to.

Answer (score 1):

SSRS is rather developer focused in that its capabilities allow detailed and explicit reports that take a developer to put together

[Izenda](http://www.izenda.com) is an excellent ad hoc reporting tool, particularly from a user focused standpoint. It has na open API for deep customization, but with a simple point and click interface geared to your average user to whip up unique reports without the involvement of a developer